# Plot time series linear regression in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, linear-regression

My question is about the representation of time series analysis from `tslm` with `ggplot2`.

I have used `forecast` package to decompose SST time series in the Mediterranean in trend, seasonal and remainder components. Then I have looked for the slope (trend) of the linear regression for the trend component with `tslm`. But I can't figure out how to plot the `tslm` with ggplot2. Should I ggplot SST trend component with `geom_smooth(model=lm)`? Would `lm` provide the same results (slope) than `tslm`?

This is the code used to build and decompose SST time series

```
library(forecast)

# Loop to calculate trend for any grid point/column
for (i in 2:length(data)){

  # read variable/column to analyse
  var<-paste("V",i,sep="")
  ff<-data$fecha
  valor<-data[,i]  
  datos2<-as.data.frame(cbind(data$fecha,valor))

  #Build time series
  datos.ts<-ts(datos2$valor, frequency = 365)
  datos.stl <- stl(datos.ts,s.window = 365)

  # tslm: Save trend component
  datos.tslm<-tslm(datos.ts ~ trend)
  output[,i-1]<-datos.stl$time.series[,2] 
}

# Summarize trends for the whole Mediterranean (mean value to be plotted)    
trend<-as.data.frame(rowMeans(output[,1:length(output)]))
```

And the code to plot with geom_smooth

```
trend.plot<-ggplot(data=trend, aes(x=fecha, y=trend)) + geom_point(size=0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', data = trend[1:12784,])
```

**EDIT 1**

As SST data consists of a bunch of files, I've uploaded trend data to Dropbox and made available in this [csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/93w8l500pquxfvc/trend_data.csv?dl=0)

Comment: did you try `method=tslm`? It [seem to be a thin wrapper around lm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.1/topics/tslm) and might provide a imilar output ggplot can deal with

Comment: @RobinGertenbach It does not work as `tslm` works for time series and `trend` it is not. It gives this error message `Computation failed in stat_smooth(): Not time series data, use lm() `

Comment: I tried running your code. Can you define what **data** is in the beginning of the for loop?

Comment: I second the motion, can you add a script to create some data for us? There are many examples on SO of doing this. It will give us important parameters to work with such as the number of variables and number of observations for each variable...

Comment: Hi @RichPauloo trend data uploaded to a csv file

Comment: What is `output` supposed to be?  Do I need to declare something in the top of the code which I'm copying from you?

Comment: Hi @lebelinoz I would like to plot the time series with linear regression obtained from `tslm`. The trend time series is composed of the trend component of the SST time series, removing seasonality and remainder components. Don't want to use just `lm`

Comment: You didn't answer my question. When I run your sample code, I get an error saying `output` isn't already defined when I do `output[, i-1] = ...`. What's missing?

Comment: @lebelinoz The content of `output` is built iin the for loop from 12784 daily files. I can not supply all the original data. `output` is summarized with `row.means` to trend object. This trend data is what I supplied on the link. Thanks for your interest

Comment: I don't see a problem. `tslm(y ~ trend)` without seasonal component is literally a linear regression.

Comment: Try, autoplot(datos.tslm).

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand you question and as the first try, I have revised your code as following (the data attached only contains 2 columns, so I removed the `for loop`, but generalization should not be hard)

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

data <- read.csv('../Downloads/trend_data.csv', header=TRUE)
data$fecha <- as.Date(data$fecha) 

i <- 2
# read variable/column to analyse
var<-paste("V",i,sep="")
ff<-data$fecha
valor<-data[,i]  
datos2<-as.data.frame(cbind(data$fecha,valor))

#Build time series
datos.ts<-ts(datos2$valor, frequency = 365)
datos.stl <- stl(datos.ts,s.window = 365)

# tslm: Save trend component
datos.tslm<-tslm(datos.ts ~ trend)
output <-datos.stl$time.series[,2]

# Summarize trends for the whole Mediterranean (mean value to be plotted)    
# trend<-as.data.frame(rowMeans(output[,1:length(output)]))  

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=fecha, y=trend)) + geom_point(size=0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', data = data.frame(fecha=data$fecha, trend=output), aes(x=fecha, y=output))
```

Let me know if I misinterpret your intention here.

**UPDATE**: I feel like what you want might be just line plot of the output trend of `tslm`?

```
 ggplot(data=data, aes(x=fecha, y=trend)) + geom_point(size=0.1) +
      geom_line(data = data.frame(fecha=data$fecha, trend=output), aes(x=fecha, y=output))
```

If you want a smoothed version of the trend,

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=fecha, y=trend)) + geom_point(size=0.1, col="red") +
  geom_smooth(data = data.frame(fecha=data$fecha, trend=output), aes(x=fecha, y=output),col="blue",size=0.1)
```

Comment: Hi, with data supplied the `for loop` was not necessary. I provided the data to be plotted. Actually, my question is about plotting `tslm` output. The for loop uses `tslm` for linear regression but `ggplot` only knows about `lm` and results slightly differ between `tslm` and `lm` when plotting. `tslm` is appropiate for linear regression in time series.

Answer (score 0):

The data you provided, plotted as a linegraph with one dot per day. Does this solve your problem?

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)

    trend_data <- read.csv2("../trend_data.csv",
                    sep = ",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    df <- trend_data %>% mutate(fecha = as.Date(fecha), trend = as.numeric(trend))

    ggplot(df, aes(x = fecha, y = trend)) +
     geom_line() + 
     geom_point()
```

Comment: Hi @wadwas, this only plots the time series, I can do that. I want to apply `tslm` as `geom_smooth` if possible

Comment: What column do you want to base the geom_smooth on?